# Android: progress dialog raises on close

Tags: android, performance, progressdialog

I have made a Util class to open and close progress dialog like this

Utils.java

```
public class Utils {

    private static Utils util;
    private Typeface typeface;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public static Utils getInstance(){

        if(util == null){
            util = new Utils();
        }
        return util;
    }

    public void showProgressDialog(Activity activity){

        if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()){
            return;
        }

        if(progressDialog == null ) {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        }
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
     }

public void closeProgressDialog(){
    try {
        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            progressDialog = null;
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

and then i call showProgressDialog before loading data and closeProgressDialog after data has been loaded. like this

Acvitity code

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard,container,false);
    activity = getActivity();
    ButterKnife.bind(this,view);

    init();
    return view;
}

  private void init() {

    Utils.getInstance().showProgressDialog(activity);
    getPatientsList();


   //in response i am calling closeProgressDialog();
  }

 public void onPatientListResponse(String response){
         Utils.getInstance().closeProgressDialog(); // raises exception here
  }
```

but it raises exception  in closeProgressDialog();

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{f7fd12e V.E...... R......D 0,0-1024,232} not attached to window manager
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

Anyway u r checking whether the progressDialog is already showing if yes u r just returning the control. Rather than that dismiss the progressDialog and create a new instance. Because old progressDialog may started with different context.

```
public void showProgressDialog(Activity activity){

        if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()){
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            progressDialog = null;
        }

        if(progressDialog == null ) {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        }
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

        if(!activity.isFinishing())
           progressDialog.show();
     }
```

Comment: thanks a lot.Actually in the previous activity i did not called closeProgressDialog() before calling new activity.So in new activity on calling showProgressDialog() it just returned previous dialog. So the dialog previous activity and i was calling closedialog in the new activity.Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Now i make sure to call closedialog before leaving activity or fragment.

Comment: @Androidjack Glad! that helped:)

Answer (score 1):

```
 public void showProgressDialog(Activity activity){

        if(progressDialog != null){  // Ensure it's not null
          if(progressDialog.isShowing()) // if it's showing than return.
            return;
        }else{
          //It will create an instance of new object.
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        }

        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
     }
```

Comment: @Raghavendra no he has checked not null than it's checking isVisible and i did separate a null condition to ensure it's not an null first.

Comment: I think u already knew this, in if condition if there are 2 conditions if the first one fails it won't check the second one right in that case what he is doing is looks fine to me.

Comment: Yes correct it will never come into an condition and one more thing added part is else for initiate progress dialog object cause they have mentioned (progressDialog == null) to create object and it seem like weird .

Answer (score 0):

You have not even initialized your progress bar and you're trying to check if it's showing...

here you have not initialized your progressbar but since your condition is && (AND), compiler is supposed to check both and found progressDialog is null, hence there is no isShowing method for it...

```
if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()){
        return;
    }
--------------------------------------------------
public void showProgressDialog(Activity activity){
    if(progressDialog == null ) {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    }
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();
 }
```

One suggestion is use Context instead of activity for your progressbar.

Cheers!

Comment: where i haven't initialized it?

Comment: yes but i checked it its not giving exception there.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this issue before and solved using the below code.

```
private boolean isDialogViewAttachedToWindowManager() {
    if (dialog.getWindow() == null) return false;
    View decorView = progressDialog.getWindow().getDecorView();
    return decorView != null && decorView.getParent() != null;
}
```

Or try the below solution.

```
if (pDialog instanceof Activity && !((Activity) mContext).isFinishing())
        pDialog.show();
```